# C# questions regarding coding

Tags: c#

If I have a Pet class with the get set methods for int, double and bool

is this correct?

```
public class Pet
{
  private string name;
  private bool age;
  public Pet(string name, bool age)
  {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
  }
  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
  }
  public bool Age
  {
    get { return age; }
    set { age = value; }
  }
}
```

Main Method

```
Pet myPet = new Pet ("james", true);
```

would it be fine to put true in the object for bool?

Comment: This is the Class constructor not the object class

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, what does the get set methods have to do with the line of code? What do you mean by "correct"?

Comment: Based on the edit: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I would still say its wrong because True or False aren't really valid representations of an age. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

For this you'll have to create a custom constructor like:

```
public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    public bool Alive { get; set; }

    //defining a custom constructor
    public Pet(string name, float weight, bool alive)
    {
        this.Name = name;      //assign input parameter value to the Property
        this.Weight = weight;
        this.Alive = alive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class has int, double and bool properties then this object constructor

```
Pet myPet = new Pet("fish", 20.0, true);
```

Would not compile. The "fish" parameter is a string and the compiler will fail (assuming you're setting the property values in the object constructor)

Comment: thanks. therefore if it's Pet myPet = new Pet(1, 20.0, true); it will be correct?

Comment: At first sight, yes, but you need to check the constructor code. It's not a direct assignment of the properties like in setters. The constructor has a logic in it, you need to check if the first parameter is assigned to the int property, the second to the double, and so on. Another alternative is to use inline constructor: new Pet { YourStringParameter = "fish", YourDoubleParameter = 20.0, YourBoolParameter = true };

Answer (score 0):

You need an constructor for it:

```
public class Pet
{
    public Pet(string type, double price, bool something)
    {
    }
}
```